# Why don't I need to declare an exception in a method [Java]?

Tags: java, exception, throw, throws

In the following Code::

```
public class Main {
  static void checkAge(int age) {
    if (age < 18) {
      throw new ArithmeticException("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Access granted - You are old enough!");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkAge(19);
    checkAge(17);
  }
}
```

> https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp

Shouldn't I add throws to
`static void checkAge(int age) throws ArithmeticException{` ?

---

Also, if I change the `ArithmeticException` to `Exception`, then I have to use `throw`. Why?

```
public class Main {
  static void checkAge(int age) throws Exception {
    if (age < 18) {
      throw new Exception("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Access granted - You are old enough!");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    checkAge(19);
    checkAge(17);
  }
}
```

Comment: read about checked and unchecked exceptions

Comment: As Eran says ^^^.  Note that `ArithmeticException` is an uncheck exception.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of [Understanding checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java)